# PlanningScene Message fields

Tags: arm-navigation

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In the [PlanningScene](http://www.ros.org/doc/electric/api/arm_navigation_msgs/html/msg/PlanningScene.html) message definition there is a field:

```
#additional frames for duplicating tf
geometry_msgs/TransformStamped[] fixed_frame_transforms
```

My understanding is that the robot state (or whatever other field in the message) will be transformed (translated, rotated) by the amount specified in the fixed_frame_transforms (chaining?)

Is this correct? Is this a way to plan starting from a robot position which is not the real one?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11597/planningscene-message-fields/) by [Lorenzo Riano](https://answers.ros.org/users/155/lorenzo-riano/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1342 on 2011-10-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Lorenzo,

The purpose of this field is so that we can re-create a full snapshot of the TF tree given a PlanningScene.  In the robot_state we store the transform between the world frame and the robot frame as well as all the joint states, but this doesn't include frames that are not associated with the robot, such as a /map frame if we operating in /odom_combined, extra world sensors frames, and the like.  As I answered in [this question](http://answers.ros.org/question/2496/arm-navigation-with-a-virtual-robot), you just want to set different values in the robot_state member of the planning_scene_diff to pose the robot in a different location.

---

Originally posted by [egiljones](https://answers.ros.org/users/82/egiljones/) with karma: 2031 on 2011-10-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Lorenzo Riano](https://answers.ros.org/users/155/lorenzo-riano/) on 2011-10-19**:
Great! Can you please edit your answer so that it links to the previous question? Thanks!